# PayPal Limitation

Tags: paypal

I'd like to embed a PayPal donate button on my website. But the problem is I live in Iran -- the country is sanctioned and people don't use international bank accounts or major credit cards.

Any thoughts? Please help!

Regards

Frustrated

Comment: I understand that this isn't easy to deal with, but I find this non-programming related and thus will vote to close. Please read the FAQ for more information about the types of questions to ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: migrate from Iran is the best solution :-)

Comment: You just upvoted by Israeli. Hope for a better future for both of us :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use donate buttons inside Iran for people in Iran.  For international?  Have you called paypal?  Probably an exercise in more frustration.  Still maybe they can tell you if you use a donate button, whether a person outside Iran can donate to your paypal account.

If you use two different types of buttons for inside and outside, simply specify them that way with different descriptions.

Comment: Along with Yossico - I have Israeli family.  And hope for a better future for everyone.